# Content Moderator: Text-moderation: No autocorrect for German language?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Why does autocorrect not work for German (deu)? It only shows normalized text in the response. Other languages seem to work fine.

https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/contentmoderator/moderate/v1.0/ProcessText/Screen?autocorrect=True&classify=True&language=deu

Comment: What's the text you're trying to test?

Comment: I tried several texts to test e.g.

Seit ich 2017 den gipfel des mount everest bestiegen und 2007 den südlichten punkt der erde erreicht hatte traumte ich dafon auf den dritten pol den nordpool zu begehen

Answer (score 0):

Content Moderator's autocorrect feature does not support German.

We have added the list of supported languages for the autocorrect feature to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/content-moderator/text-moderation-api-languages

We don't have plans for adding auto-correction support for German on our roadmap yet.

Thanks,

Sanjeev